# Changing color of column header in DBGrid with Theme settings on

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, tdbgrid

Is it possible to change background color of Title in TDBGrid if i have some project appearance style, for example Iceberg Classico?

This code works fine when i turn off project appearance and change Grids drawing style to classic

```
 DBGrid1.DrawingStyle := gdsClassic;  
 DBGrid1.Columns[0].Title.Color := clRed;
```

Otherwise this is not working.

Can the color be changed without changing drawing style and appearance?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change the DBGrid
`DrawingStyle` properity to `gdsGradient` & then change the `gradentEndColor` & `gradentStartColor` to be the same color ..